# Django REST Framework - Weird Parameter Shape due to JSON Parser?

Tags: python, json, django, parsing, django-rest-framework

Currently I'm contacting my APIViews through AJAX requests on my frontend.

```js
config = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 2,
    param3: 3
}

$.ajax(APIEndpoints.renderConfig.url, {
    type: APIEndpoints.renderConfig.method,
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken },
    data: {
        "config": config,
        "useWorkingConfig": true
    }
}
```

However, when I receive the data in my APIView, I get an object with the following shape:

```py
{
    "config[param1]": 1,
    "config[param2]": 2,
    "config[param3]": 3,
    "useWorkingConfig": true
}
```

According to different sources that I have checked, DRF does support nested JSON objects, so what am I missing? Is this something to do with the default behavior of the JSON Parser? It doesn't seem to be very useful, as you would basically need to preprocess the data before using your serializers (since they expect a nested structure). The same happens with lists, with your parameters being received as `list_param[]` instead of `list_param`.

If its useful for anything, these are my DRF settings

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'django_project.api.exception_handler.custom_exception_handler',

    # Camel Case Package Settings
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
    ],
    'JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE': {
        'no_underscore_before_number': True,
    },
}
```

Its very probable that Im just missing something or its an intended behavior that Im not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are experiencing is related to the default behavior of the jQuery $.ajax() method when sending data as an object in the data parameter.

By default, it serializes the object into a string of key-value pairs using the format "**key1=value1&key2=value2**". This format is not compatible with the nested JSON format that DRF expects.

To send the data in the correct format, you need to set the contentType and data parameters as follows:

```
config = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 2,
    param3: 3
};

$.ajax({
    url: APIEndpoints.renderConfig.url,
    type: APIEndpoints.renderConfig.method,
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        config: config,
        useWorkingConfig: true
    })
});
```

By setting the contentType parameter to "application/json", you are telling jQuery to send the data as a JSON string in the request body. By using JSON.stringify() to convert the config object into a JSON string, you are sending the data in the correct format that DRF expects.

Note that you may also need to update your DRF settings to handle the correct JSON format. One option is to use the JSONParser with the content_type parameter set to "application/json":

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        [...]
    ],
}
```

But you already done that i see.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that the JSONParser was to blame here. Never considered AJAX to be the cause. Previously I used AJAX to make requests to my backend but never ran into this problem, maybe because regular Django parses requests a bit better natively. But this was great to know. Thank you!

One question though: If you dont specify the content type of an AJAX call, does it change depending on the method specified?